# Removing a margin from a footer with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the footer to shown only when the page is fully scrolled down and not stay fixed on the screen, as it currently does.

The problem is that on either side, the footer has a margin of a few pixels. How do I remove this?

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../assets/footer.png");
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

footer>p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6667;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1> Some text </h1>

<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; <a href="link" class="white_link">Link</a> 2021. All Rights Reserved.
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why the `display: table;` on the `.footer`?

Comment: Your ```footer``` class is the only thing in your body aside from the ```h1``` that's why it's the only thing you're really seeing. You need o add positioning to it and tell it to go to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove margin, you should set body margins to 0. Also, if you want to force footer to stay at the bottom of the page, you should set min-height to your body and take advantage of flex. Here is the code snippet:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../assets/footer.png");
  background-position: center;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

footer>p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6667;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1> Some text </h1>
</main>

<footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; <a href="link" class="white_link">Link</a> 2021. All Rights Reserved.
  </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body tag seems to have margins applied
[image]

Add this in your css

```
.body {
   margin:0;
 }
```